# How to locate files for GPSD in Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, gps, file

I am trying to find where the program gpsd is saved because I need to edit a file to get my pi and gps to talk.

I have been following instructions from http://www.instantsupportsite.com/self-help/raspberry-pi/raspberry-globalsat-353s4-install/.

I believe my target file (gpsd.hotplug) is saved somewhere else then what my instructions suggest because when I enter `nano /lib/udev/gpsd.hotplug`, I get a new blank text file.

How do I track down gpsd.hotplug and more generally, the location gpsd is installed?

I have tried `find gpsd.hotplug` but was greeted with `find: 'gpsd.hotplug': No such file or directory`.

I am running raspbian version 4.1.13.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't really tell what your question is.  However, I just posted a quick Q&A on setting up gpsd.  For me, the only changes I needed to make were external to the daemon.  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68816/how-can-i-set-up-my-g-mouse-usb-gps-for-use-with-raspbian/68817#68817

Comment: Here is a link to the Hacker's Guide branch of the gpsd Home Page:  http://www.catb.org/gpsd/hacking.html - Have you looked there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `find`, a directory is needed as well. The command you should be using is:

```
find gpsd.hotplug /
```

or:

```
sudo ls -aR / | grep "gpsd.hotplug" -B 15
```

Comment: I tried both options and did not find the file so the file probably does not exist. How could I find where the GPSD directory is? I have tried your above suggestions replacing `gpsd.hotplug` with both `gpsd` and `cgps` Thank you so much!

Comment: @JordanWalters you can use `sudo ls -aR / | grep gpsd`

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the files by using this command:

```
sudo find / gpsd | grep gpsd
```

Here are the results on my system:
[image]

[image]